# Interpreting time series dimension?

Tags: matlab, time-series, feature-extraction

I am wondering if anyone can explain the interpretation of the size (number of feature) in a time series? For example consider a simple script in Matlab

```
X= randn(2,5,2)
X(:,:,1) =

   -0.5530    0.4291    0.3937   -1.2534    0.2811
   -1.4926   -0.7019   -0.8305   -1.4034    1.9545


X(:,:,2) =

    0.2004    0.1438    2.3655   -0.1589    0.7140
    0.4905    0.2301   -0.7813   -0.6737    0.2552
```

Assume X is a time series with the following output
This generates 2 vectors of length 5 each has 2 rows. Can anyone tell me what is exactly the meaning of first 2 and 5? 
In some websites it says a creating 5 vectors of length 5 and size 2. What does size mean here? 
Is 2 like number of features and 5 is like number of time series. The reason for this confusion is because I do not understand how to interpret following sentence:

> "Generate 2 vector-valued sequences of length 5; each vector has size
>   2."
>    What do  size 2 and length 5 mean here?

Answer (score 0):

This entirely depends on your data, and how you want to store this. If you have some 2D data over time, I find it convenient to have a data matrix with in the 1st and 2nd dimension the 2D data per time step, and in the 3rd dimension time.

Say I have a movie of 1920 by 1080 pixels with 100 frames, I'd store this as `mov = rand(1080,1920,100)` (1080 and 1920 swapped because of `row`, `col` order of indexing). So now `mov(:,:,1)` would give me the first frame etc.

BTW, your `X` is a normal array, not to be confused with the [`timeseries`](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries.html) object.

Comment: Thanks I updated my question, and added the original confusing statement. I need to be able to interpret the above sentence correctly